# Can't access to the container even if it is running

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a Flask API in a docker container. It interacts with other containers so I put everything in a docker-compose.
When I run `docker-compose up` the containers are successfully built and run, but I am not able to access to my API, neither from the browser nor with Python's `requests` module.

I will now paste here the Dockerfile with the configuration for the API's container:

```
FROM python:3.8.16-bullseye
RUN apt-get update
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN mkdir "jobs"
COPY . /counter_sairus
WORKDIR /counter_sairus
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "api.py"]
```

And this is the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "2.3"

services:
    api:
        container_name: api
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        environment:
            - BROKER_URI=redis://redis
            - BACKEND_URI=redis://redislistening on
        depends_on:
            - worker
            - redis
        volumes:
            -   ./jobs:/counter_sairus/jobs
    worker:
        container_name: celery
        environment:
            - BROKER_URI=redis://redis
            - BACKEND_URI=redis://redis
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile_worker
        depends_on:
            - redis
        volumes:
            -  ./jobs:/counter_sairus/jobs
    redis:
        image: "redis:alpine3.17"
        ports:
            - 6379

networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: rete1
```

Lastly, this is the doce in `api.py` :

```
api = Api(title="API", version="0.1", description="API")
application = Flask(__name__)
api.init_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

After running the docker-compose, some log messages appear. Three of them come from the API container and are the following:

```
* Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
* Running on http://172.18.0.9:5000
```

But, as I said, neither one of the two addresses work. If I try to reach them from the browser, in both the cases I get an error saying that the page cannot be reached.
I am running this on windows. But if I run the very same code on Ubuntu, the very same logs will appear (only the IP addresses change), and everything works well. I have no idea on how to solve this, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Add a `ports` statement to the `api` section in your `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: ...the Docker-internal IP addresses in those log messages aren't normally reachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is contained by default in a container. So if you want to anything to be accessible such as a port, you need to be explicit about it.

`docker-compose` is basically just a more structured way for you to run docker commands. Now if you think about your containers and how you run them, like that, you can translate each into a `docker run` (and a `build` if you specify a dockerfile instead of anb image) command. For example your api:

```bash
docker build -t something . && docker run -d --rm celery -e ROKER_URI=redis://redis something
```

That's a little shortened, for readability.

So if you want to expose a port to be available, you'd need to tell that in the command in some way. There are multiple options, one is to [expose a port](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish). Which you would do like

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 celery something:latest
```

You will have to do the same in your compose file. (Note that there's a bit of a difference in compose between `expose` and `port` where one exposes ports to other compose services and the other publishes them to the host machine).

So you need to adapt your compose file like so:

```yaml
version: "2.3"

services:
    api:
        container_name: api
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        environment:
            - BROKER_URI=redis://redis
            - BACKEND_URI=redis://redislistening on
        depends_on:
            - worker
            - redis
        volumes:
            -   ./jobs:/counter_sairus/jobs
    ports:
      - 5000:5000 
    worker:
        container_name: celery
        environment:
            - BROKER_URI=redis://redis
            - BACKEND_URI=redis://redis
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile_worker
        depends_on:
            - redis
        volumes:
            -  ./jobs:/counter_sairus/jobs
    ports:
      - 5000:5000 
    redis:
        image: "redis:alpine3.17"
        ports:
            - 6379

networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: rete1
```

Which is what you had done for the redis service already as well.